# ArrayList gives null. I have written an observer pattern but notification is not working

Tags: java

```
package p;

public interface Observer {

    public void update(float interest);

}
```

---

```
package p;

public interface Subject {

    public void registerObserver(Observer obj);

    public void removeObserver(Observer obj);

    public void notifyObervers();


}
```

---

```
package p;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class Loan {

    private float interest;

    public float getInterest() {
        return interest;
    }

    public void setInterest(float interest) {
        System.out.println("interest received : notifying listener "+interest);
        this.interest = interest;
        subject.notifyObervers();
    }

    public List<Observer> observerList = new ArrayList<Observer>();

    Subject subject = new Subject() {

        @Override
        public void removeObserver(Observer obj) {
            observerList.remove(obj);
        }

        @Override
        public void registerObserver(Observer obj) {
            observerList.add(obj);
        }

        @Override
        public void notifyObervers() {

            for (Observer obj : observerList) {
                obj.update(getInterest());

            }

        }
    };

}
```

---

```
package p;

public class News  {

    Observer observer = new Observer() {

        @Override
        public void update(float interest) {
            System.out.println("NEWS : received interest "+interest);           
        }
    };

}
```

---

```
package p;

public class Internet {

    Observer observer = new Observer() {
        @Override
        public void update(float interest) {
            System.out.println("Internet : Received Update on interest : "+interest);           
        }
    };

}
```

---

```
package p;

public class ObserversMain {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Observer observer1 = new Internet().observer;
        Observer observer2 = new News().observer;

        Subject loan = new Loan().subject;
        loan.registerObserver(observer1);
        loan.registerObserver(observer2);

        new Loan().setInterest(6.7f);

        System.out.println("notified listeners ::: ");

    }

}
```

Comment: Post your stacktrace.

Comment: please reword and clarify what is your problem and where you are getting an error?

Answer (score 1):

You are creating instances without keeping references to them.

I'd change the code to :

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    Internet internet = new Internet ();
    News news = new News ();
    Observer observer1 = internet.observer;
    Observer observer2 = news.observer;

    Loan loan = new Loan();
    Subject subject = loan.subject;
    subject.registerObserver(observer1);
    subject.registerObserver(observer2);

    loan.setInterest(6.7f);

    System.out.println("notified listeners ::: ");

}
```